# Is it possible for decision trees to consider less features than in my training set?

Tags: decision-trees

I was looking at the decision tree algorithm and I wondered that for example if the training set has 20 features but only 5 features are important and classification can be done by using only them then will my end result decision tree has only 5 features? My understanding is that as decision tree is a kind of greedy based algorithm, so I believe it will only consider those features which can be used for the best fit of the training data and ignore the rest of them.

Comment: As far as I know the decission tree will use all features, so if you are using 20 but only 5 are informative, you are bulding a uncessary complex model. You should perform feature selection before you train de decission tree

Comment: Also, https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/57697/55122